# How to select and remove a div element if it doesn't contain text and only has <br> elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my scenario:

```
<div><br><div>
<div>
    line one.
    <br>
    line two.
</div>
<div><img src="example.jpg"></div>
<div><br></div>
<div><iframe></iframe></div>
<div><br></div>
```

I need to check if a div contains NO text and has a br tag then remove it.

---

I tried this:

```
if ($('div').is(':empty')) { 
    $('div').remove();
}
```

This didn't work I think because empty() doesn't mean "no text."

---

I also tried this:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === '';
}).remove();
```

This worked, however it removed all div tags that contained anything but text, so all my images and any other html tag inside of a div were removed.

---

The last thing I tried was this but then realized this didn't account for the text that may be in the div.

```
$('div br:only-child').remove();
```

I'm still new to jquery and apologize for any annoyance I may cause asking for help from y'all.  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I added different solution try this.

Comment: but i saw the title carefully, the title clearly mention that, he want to remove the <br> tag, so i give this answer. now i remove my answer, cause the answer not related to this actual question.

Comment: again i add new block of code, please check and let me know.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [jQuery `:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) in order to select `div` elements that have a `br` descendant element:

```
$('div:has(br)').filter(function() {
  return !this.textContent.trim();
}).remove();
```

As you mentioned in your question, you could also combine that with the [`:only-child` selector](https://api.jquery.com/only-child-selector/) if you only want to remove the `div` element if the `br` element is the only child:

```
$('div:has(br:only-child)').filter(function() {
  return !this.textContent.trim();
}).remove();
```

---

If there can be multiple `br` elements, then you obviously shouldn't be using `:only-child`.

The better approach would be to check the length of sibling elements that are not `br` elements.

```
$('div:has(>br)').filter(function() {
  return !this.textContent.trim() && !$('br', this).siblings(':not(br)').length;
}).remove();
```

In the query above, the `div` element will be removed if it doesn't contain any text and it only has descendant `br` elements. As addressed in the comments, if you only want to check for `br` elements that are direct descendants, use the child combinator, `>`, in the initial selector as well.

Comment: This answer blew my mind. I was searching through all divs and if they had no text check for the br tag to remove

Comment: Oh my goodness gracious, this worked beautifully!  Thank you so so much!

I ran into a bug however...

I have a div tag that contains an img and a br tag.  It was removed as well.

Is there a way I can target specifically:
    <div><br></div>

Just so you know the code I'm dealing with is auto generated by a wysiwyg editor.  When hitting return after an image it's throwing a br tag in after the img tag, they're both nested in a div tag.

Comment: @rholguin If they are both nested in `div` elements, then it sounds like you only want to target direct children `br` elements; you could try `$('div:has(>br:only-child)')` -> See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/ekxjq34x/1/

Comment: @Josh Oh wow, It worked perfectly! You have no idea the ginormous smile I have on my face right now!  I love smart people!  Thank you good sir, for your help, a thousand times over!!  Thank you stackoverflow!

Comment: slick one liner there!

Answer (score 1):

Check the children of the element are only `<br>` then check for empty text

```
$('div:has(br)').filter(function(){
   var $div= $(this), $children=$div.children();
   // check if all children are <br>
   if($children.length === $children.filter('br').length){
        // return true or false depending on text
        return !$div.text().trim();
   }
   // children are not all <br>
   return false;
}).remove();
```

Comment: This worked in my code just as well.  Thank you for your input and helping!  So much appreciate you all!

Answer (score 1):

I used a find and destroy approach:

https://jsfiddle.net/ay4ax3nz/

```
$("div").each(function(){
    if($(this).html() === '<br>' || $(this).html() === '<br />'){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Holy awesomeness!  I tested your code by nesting a br tag with the img and iframe tags and your code still worked!  Thank you for your input!

Comment: I added one more update to it to include .trim(). That way if you have an instance like "<br> ", it will still work.

https://jsfiddle.net/ay4ax3nz/1/